# Delete email account from android emulator?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

How do I delete email account from an android emulator? I'm using ecplise, after launching the emulator, I clicked on the email icon and logged in and now can't figure out how to delete the account.

Thanks so much in advance

Answer (score 1):

in settings, go to Accounts&Sync, then click your email account, click remove!

Answer (score 0):

You could either delete the android emulator from the Android AVD manager or you could go to the email app and then press the menu button then click on Accounts then LONG Click on the account that you want to remove and then you click on Remove Account then press Ok then your account will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind losing all data in the emulator, you can reset it.

Follow these steps:

- Turn off your Emulator
- Go to android studio -> `Device manager -> Select device -> Wipe Data`
- Run the emulator again, you find that all the previous data is gone :)

[image: Reference Image]